# Please explain why I get NA error for this: =MATCH(2,{1.2;1.9;2.6;3.8;5.5},-1)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Please note that I am getting the correct result of 2 for the formula **=MATCH(2,{1.2;1.9;2.6;3.8;5.5},1)** because the match type is 1 which finds the largest value **(1.9)** that is smaller than Lookup value.
But when I try **=MATCH(2,{1.2;1.9;2.6;3.8;5.5},-1)** which must find the smallest value **(2.6)** that is greater than the Lookup value I get NA error. The answer is supposed to be 3 because 2.6 is the value after 2 that is smallest. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The match type has to be used in combination with the right sorting of the array.

Matchttype 1 --> sort ascending

Matchttype -1 --> sort descending

Answer (score 0):

When the Match_Type is selected as 1, the lookup_array (in your case {1.2;1.9;2.6;3.8;5.5}) MUST be in the ascending order.

However, when the Match_Type is selected as -1, the lookup_array MUST be in the **descending** order.

So the correct way to use the MATCH function will be:
`=MATCH(2,{5.5;3.8;2.6;1.9;1.2},-1)`

This will return "3" as you expected (it returns relative position of the array element).

See the documentation [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a).

Answer (score 0):

Greater than option will only work if array is sorted to descending order. Try below

```
=MATCH(2,{5.5;3.8;2.6;1.9;1.2},-1)
```

[image]